# qemu failure while making chroot for raspbian

Tags: ros, raspbian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi folks,

I tried to create a chroot environmnent in accordance with ROS dox "groovy / installation / Raspbian" in ORacle VBox.
Host OS is debian-6.0.7-amd64 squeeze, 2 virtual CPU. Image file I dd'ed from SD card which has 2013-02-09 Raspbian wheezy (it's running OK on Raspberry).
Image mounted OK, I can see it under mounting point /mnt/sdb1/raspb, but when I run
sudo chroot /mnt/sdb1/raspb

qemu fails  with

qemu: fatal: cp15 insn ee070fba

and then register dump...

any ideas how this can be fixed?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56886/qemu-failure-while-making-chroot-for-raspbian/) by [tulumbas](https://answers.ros.org/users/4338/tulumbas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-03-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tulumbas](https://answers.ros.org/users/4338/tulumbas/) on 2013-03-09**:
No ideas I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Qemu chroot will not work on the latest raspbian release. It does work on the release from december. You can still download it from [here](http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/images/raspbian/2012-12-16-wheezy-raspbian/).
I will also add this information to the wiki since I had to find it out the hard way as well.

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tulumbas](https://answers.ros.org/users/4338/tulumbas/) on 2013-03-14**:
thanks for giving a clue - I've spent quite lot of time. Any ideas when fresh kernel will be supported? I appreciate you could be wrong person to ask, just wondering...

**Comment by [tulumbas](https://answers.ros.org/users/4338/tulumbas/) on 2013-03-14**:
Ah, found a branch of RasPi forum...